# Why are Sets of up to 4 elements ordered but larger ones are not?

Tags: scala, set

Given

```
val xs1 = Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val ys1 = Set(7, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3)
```

`xs1` and `ys1` both result in `scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 4)`

but smaller sets bellow

```
val xt1 = Set(1, 2, 3)
val yt1 = Set(3, 2, 1)
```

produce

```
xt1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)
yt1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(3, 2, 1)
```

Why are former not ordered whilst latter seem to be ordered?

Comment: **Set** is a trait, there are many implementations for it. Usually, for more than 4 o 5 elements you will get a `HashSet` but for 0 to 4 or 5 elements _(I really do not remember)_ there are optimized classes like `EmptySet`, `Set1`, etc. That is way they preserve the order, but that may change. Sets are not guarantee to preserve it _(but also are not guarantee to do not do it)_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference in behaviour is due to [optimisations](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a3791d4d61bd584f27e4dac8765f753a27bb95e0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L188) for Sets of [up to 4 elements](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/sets.html)

> The default implementation of an immutable set uses a representation
>   that adapts to the number of elements of the set. An empty set is
>   represented by just a singleton object. Sets of **sizes up to four** are
>   represented by a single object that stores all elements as fields.
>   Beyond that size, immutable sets are implemented as [Compressed
>   Hash-Array Mapped Prefix-tree](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/concrete-immutable-collection-classes.html#compressed-hash-array-mapped-prefix-trees).

similarly explained by [Ben James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7018941/5205022):

> Set is also a companion object* with an apply** method. When you call
>   Set(...), you're calling this factory method and getting a return
>   value which is some kind of Set. It might be a HashSet, but could be
>   some other implementation. According to 2, the default implementation
>   for an immutable set has special representation for empty set and sets
>   size up to 4. Immutable sets size 5 and above and mutable sets all use
>   hashSet.

Since size of `Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7)` is greater than 4, then its concrete implementation is `HashSet`

```
Set(3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7).getClass
class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet
```

which does [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5246204/5205022) guarantee insertion order. On the other hand, concrete implementation of `Set(1, 2, 3)` is dedicated class [`Set3`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/a3791d4d61bd584f27e4dac8765f753a27bb95e0/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L190)

```
Set(1,2,3).getClass
class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set3
```

which stores the three elements in corresponding three *fields*

```
final class Set3[A] private[collection] (elem1: A, elem2: A, elem3: A) extends AbstractSet[A] ...
```